# Printing a method

Tags: java

I need to call a method that returns the code below. I am using it in an enhanced for loop with objects in the array. However, when I try to print it out, I get an error.

```
public String toString(){
    return String.format("Length:%d\nWidth:%d\nHeight:%d\n", length,width,height);
```

This is used for my main.

```
for(Box n:boxes)
System.out.printf(n.toString());
```

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double

Comment: You want %f if those values are doubles

Comment: %d is for integers, %f for double types, and your variables are Double!

Comment: Never knew about that haha I'm still a beginner!Thank you guys so much for the info!